# Reading a workbooks without opening it with ADO

Tags: vba, excel, ado

After this question: [get value/charts in another workbooks without opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840573/get-value-charts-in-another-workbooks-without-opening-it)

I have coded this:

```
Sub test()

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

oConn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
oConn.Properties("Extended Properties").Value = "Excel 8.0"
oConn.Open "C:\Workbook1.xlsm"
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [A1:A2];", oConn, adOpenStatic

rst.MoveFirst
MsgBox rst.Fields(0)

rst.Close
oConn.Close

End Sub
```

For the moment my goal is to get the value in the `cell A1` of the `sheet 1` of `workbook1.xlsm`.

I've encountered two problems.

When the `workbook1` is not opened I got a

```
Run time error '-214767259 (80004005)': Automation error Unspecified Error on the line      oConn.Open "C:\Workbook1.xlsm`
```

This is annoying because I want to work without opening the workbooks. It works well when the workbook is open.

Second problem: I can't manage to only get a single cell value. I've tried to input only `[A1]` in `rst.open` but it doesn't work. How can I get a unique cell value with its address ? with its name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind I'll provide you a bit different attempt to get your data. The difference is the way you connect with you database (excel sheet). However, you could possibly incorporate some important elements into your code. So, check comments inside the code below.

```
Sub Closed_excel_workbook()

    Dim myConnection As String
    Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String

'connection string parameters
'CHANGE PATH TO YOUR CLOSED WORKBOOK
    myConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Dane\BazaDanych.xlsx;" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

'here is important, YOU CAN'T MISS SHEET NAME
    mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [ARKUSZ1$a1:a2]"

'different way of getting data from excel sheet
    Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    myRecordset.Open mySQL, myConnection, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

'let's clear sheet before pasting data
'REMOVE IF NOT NEEDED
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

'HERE WE PASTING DATA WE HAVE RETRIEVED
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myRecordset

'OPTIONAL, IF REQUIRED YOU CAN ADD COLUMNS NAMES
    Dim cell As Range, i!
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        For i = 0 To myRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = myRecordset.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got the same error on the line:  > myRecordset.Open mySQL, myConnection, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

Comment: I now have found a way to do it without ADODB connection, using ExecuteExcel4Macro. It is working well and seems very simple. Do you know about it ? what is your opinion ?

Comment: Your idea is an old macro type which you call. If it's working it's fine, you should be afraid of anything. It's not just up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
Function GetValue()

Path = "C:\Path\"
    File = "Doc.xlsm"
    Sheet = "Sheet_name"
    Ref = "D4"

     'Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim Arg As String
     'Make sure the file exists
   If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
   If Dir(Path & File) = "" Then
       GetValue = "File not  Found"
       Exit Function
    End If
     'Create the argument
    Arg = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & CStr(Sheet) & "'!" & Range(Ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
     'Check the value

     MsgBox Arg

    'Execute XML

    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Arg)
End Function
```

It has the advantage of not using complex adodb connection, but may be less powerfull.